# How to create an ID that links rows based on multiple fields

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to create GROUP_ID based on information present in two other fields. All ID_1 having same values must have a unique Group_ID and likewise, all ID_2 having same values must have a unique Group_ID. The Group_ID need not be contiguous.

```
ID_1    ID_2    GROUP_ID  
X1      10      1  
X1      20      1  
Y1      30      2  
Y2      30      2  
A1      100     3  
A1      200     3  
B1      200     3  
B1      200     3  
B1      300     3  
B1      300     3  
C1      300     3  
C1      400     3
```

I am using pyspark and I tried to solve in Spark SQL using window functions (see below), but unable to produce the desired output. Please let me know if there is an efficient way to solve this. My dataset is having >100M rows.

```
RowNum  ID_1    ID_2    ID_1_1  ID_2_1  GROUP_ID
1       X1      10      1       1       1
2       X1      20      1       1       1
3       Y1      30      3       3       3
4       Y2      30      4       3       3
5       A1      100     5       5       5
6       A1      200     5       5       5
7       B1      200     7       5       5
8       B1      200     7       5       5
9       B1      300     7       7       5
10      B1      300     7       7       5
11      C1      300     11      7       7
12      C1      400     11      11      7

Where
ID_1_1 = First(ROWNUM) over (Partition by ID_1 order by RowNum)
ID_2_1 = First(ID_1_1) over (Partition by ID_2 order by ID_1_1)
Group_ID = First(ID_2_1) over (Partition by ID_1_1 order by ID_2_1)

Using above approach, Rows 11 and 12 gets a group ID of 7 instead of 5.
```

Comment: why do you way that row 11 and 12 should have 5 as groupID?

Comment: Because otherwise, all 300 in ID_2 and C1 in ID_1  won't have the same group_id

Comment: You should look up connected components algorithms. I am not sure if there's an easy sql query to achieve this.